# Structural correctness while refactoring in Clojure

Tags: clojure

If my project is using "person" maps with the shape `{:firstName :lastName :address}`, and I want to change that shape to `{:name {:firstName :lastName} :address}`, what can I do to help ensure that I've made the corresponding changes everywhere these objects are used?

In Java, it's straightforward as anywhere I still have person.firstName would issue a compile error.  In Clojure I *might* not even get a *runtime* error, but just bad data saved to the server.  I assume it's not possible to *guarantee* correctness, but what is there other than fine-toothed-combs?

Comment: If you want compile-time errors, you might also consider using `core.typed`.

Comment: The answers that have been given are good, but I'll note that this may be a situation in which familiarity with regular expression search and replace in a good programmer's editor could be very useful.  If regular expressions aren't flexible enough, and you have a large code base, it might even be worth coding up a text manipulation script in your favorite language for string manipulation.  Or you might even use Clojure.  It is, after all, very good at reading Clojure source, and Clojure macros are good at rewriting Clojure source.  This all depends on how much code you have to refactor.

Answer (score 6):

Clojure has libraries that provide data definition and validation. For example, you could use https://github.com/Prismatic/schema

Regarding the difficulty of compile-time vs. runtime errors...well, that issue is not unique to Clojure. To quote John Carmack: "The challenge of lisp is getting your program to run, the challenge of Haskell is getting it to compile."

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @noahlz - if you want to be really sure then, you'll have to use a library like the one he's suggested. Large refactoring with maps *can* be a problem, it's true.

Having said that, you could slightly improve your chances in your case if you used a Record with its constructor function to create your `person` (and still retain the good things about maps):

```
(defrecord Person [name address])

;; Okay. No problem
(def scott (->Person {:firstname "Scott" :lastname "Lowe"}
                     "23 Hope Street, Edinburgh"))
;; But then...
(def scott (->Person "Scott"
                     "Lowe"
                     "23 Hope Street, Edinburgh"))
;; Boom!
ArityException Wrong number of args (3) passed to: user/eval990/->Person--1005
```

Now this example catches the issue at runtime, and it will obviously only help in some simple cases. But static analysis tools will also pick up on this bug at development time (for example: Clojure plugins like Cursive available for IntelliJ).